# How to GET Restful data for a particular id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-ui-router, ngresource

I'm new to AngularJS and i would like to pass an id to my URI (from which i would make a rest call). To illustrate my problem better here's an example:

If a user clicks on a link with `ui-sref="{{result.id}}"` in my `app.js` I have something like -

```
$stateProvider.state("",{

url:"/{{result.id}}",
controller : "artleFeed",
templateUrl: "Feed/feed.html"
```

Now I want to make a rest call with url something like -`Mybackendproject/xyz/users/id`

Now i want to pass my result.id to rest call url - `id`

I have read other people's post on how `ngResource` could do it and honestly didn't quite understand.

I would be really thankful if you could help me figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply define your state like this:

```
$stateProvider.state("result", {
  url: "/:id",
  controller : "articleFeed",
  templateUrl: "Feed/feed.html"
});
```

Then in the articleFeed controller, you reference $stateParams.id to access this variable:

```
.controller('articleFeed', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, ArticleService) {
  ArticleService.get({ id: $stateParams.id }, function (data) {
    $scope.article = data;
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm using a factory for making the rest call, so any suggestions for that?

Comment: @AnshAgarwal see my modified comment above.